# What is this meaning "if(<an integer> & 2)"?

Tags: java, c++, if-statement, int

What is this meaning `"if(<an integer> & 2)"`? I saw it [here](http://3dgep.com/?p=1053) but I write it to java and the compiler not accept it. Pls help me!

Comment: Testing the second bit from the right to see if it's on.

Comment: It's a bitwise-and operator. You can google it to learn more about what it does.

Comment: (Note that the third bit from the right would not be tested with 3, but with 4.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be `if ((integer & 2) != 0)`.

Java does not recognize positive integers as `true` and `0` as `false` like in `C++`.

Otherwise it tests if the second bit from the right is set, i.e it is 1.

Comment: It isn't `> 0`, it is `!= 0`. It is equivalent in this case, but confusing answers to newbie posts should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

That's because Java does not implicitly case `0` to `false`.

In C++, `0` is `false`, so `1 & 2` = 0 which is false.

While in Java, `1 & 2` is still 0, but 0 cannot be treated as `false`, thus the compiler told you there's a type mismatch.

Comment: @user2521581 - look at my post. Add `> 0`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise operator and gives you the 2nd bit.

For example:

```
# In binary:
1 = 0001    & 2: 0000
2 = 0010    & 2: 0010
3 = 0011    & 2: 0010
4 = 0100    & 2: 0000
5 = 0101    & 2: 0000
6 = 0110    & 2: 0010
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called a "bitwise and". It takes its two arguments and returns an integer value with only the bits that are 1 in both arguments set to 1 and all the rest are 0.

The reason that doesn't work in Java is because Java `if` statements only accept `boolean` values.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` symbol takes the bitwise AND of the two given numbers.

 For instance, take 5 AND 7 in binary:
`0101 & 0111 = 0101`

 more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

When used in an IF statement, the compiler will essentially check if resulting number is 0 and return false or if it is anything other number it will return true.